# Using Python, how do I remove duplicates in a PANDAS dataframe column while keeping/ignoring all 'nan' values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, drop-duplicates

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
     "siteID": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan'],
     "date": [42, 30, 43, 29, 26, 34, 10, 14],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

But I want to delete any duplicates in siteID, keeping only the most up-to-date value AND keeping all 'nan' values.

I get close with this code:

```
df_no_dup = df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('siteID', keep='last')
```

which only keeps the siteID with the highest date value. The issue is that most of the rows with 'nan' for siteID are being removed when I want to ignore them all. Is there any way to keep all the rows where siteID is equal to 'nan'?

Expected output:

```
siteID  date
    nan 10
    nan 14
    2   30
    nan 34
    1   42
    3   43
```

Comment: Hi! Please provide the output you would expect for this example.

Comment: @Stef expected output has been added, thanks!

Comment: Group by 'siteID' and construct a new df using logic to only keep what you want. Filter out the nan's then drop dupes on the rest then reconstruct.

Comment: Are your nan's actually strings or numpy.nan or...?

Comment: @wwii they are strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `df.duplicated` to create a custom condition.

Like this

```py
df.drop(df[df.sort_values('date').duplicated('siteID', keep='last') & (df.siteID!='nan')].index)
```

Result

```
  siteID  date
0      1    42
1      2    30
2      3    43
5    nan    34
6    nan    10
7    nan    14
```